# How to configure citrix presentation server 4.5 login config

Tags: citrix

I am a little confused as to something my Citrix Server has been doing. When I login to the web login, (username, password, domain); everything logs in ok and I see all the available application.

The problem that I was trying to fix is that when I try to start an application, it asks me to login again to the server that is hosting the citrix server. **So, is there anyway to have the initial login credentials pass-through to the server login or skip the server login completely?**

Side note - I do have pass-through authentication enabled on both my internal and external Citrix site.

Thanks for the help!

Cory

Answer (score 0):

I'm just bumping this because it's been happening to us, too. It's not too much hassle to have our users re-type their credentials and select our Windows domain, but the fact that they have to do so irks me as it suggests that something is misconfigured. The odd thing about it is that it's not consistent--it happens to me about half the time that I log in, but not always, and there's no pattern that I've found to when it does or does not happen.

Comment: An answer should provide information to help and not be a "me too".

Answer (score 0):

Check that the time on your workstation and your XenApp server match.  Also, check the ICA listener and ensure the "prompt for password" box is not checked.  Also make sure that the proper permissions are set on the ICA listner.  If none of these steps work, try logging in with a different AD account.  I have seen situations where one user's account will always prompt for a login for no apparent reason, but when they use a different account it works fine.